# openpyxl first column is empty when using append method

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm new to Python, and i'm programming a simple math question program. The user is prompted a math question, and the user have to type the correct answer. All of the questions, solutions and answers are saved to a local excel ark. That is the summary of my project, now comes the problem:

[image]

When i append resultsArr the question column is blank in the excel ark. When i print resultArr i get an array back with the question as the first index in the array.

[image]

So i get an array back with all of the values, but for some reason it doesn't accept the first index. I have tried to manually write a string in its place, and that works.

**main.py - current version**

```
from colors import colors
from mathQuestion import mathQuestion
from openpyxl import Workbook

gameResults = []
score = 0


def saveData(rows):
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.append(["Question", "Answer", "Solution"])
    [ws.append(x) for x in rows]
    wb.save("data.xlsx")
    wb.close()


while True:
    result = mathQuestion()
    gameResults.append(
        [result["question"], result["answer"], result["solution"]])

    if(result["answer"] == result["solution"]):
        score += 1
        print(f"{colors.green}Correct{colors.default}, your current score: {colors.yellow+str(score)+colors.default}")
    else:
        print(colors.red+"Game Over"+colors.default)
        break

saveData(gameResults)
```

**mathQuestion.py**

```
from random import randint
from colors import colors


def oddOrEven():
    number = randint(1, 1000)
    numberIsOdd = number % 2 != 0
    question = f"Is {number} odd or even: "

    if(numberIsOdd):
        solution = "odd"
    else:
        solution = "even"

    while True:
        userInput = input(question)
        if(userInput == "odd" or userInput == "even"):
            return {
                "answer": userInput,
                "question": question,
                "solution": solution
            }
        else:
            print("Only odd or even")


def muliply():
    a = randint(0, 10)
    b = randint(0, 10)
    question = f"What is {a} * {b}:  "
    solution = a*b

    while True:
        userInput = input(question)
        try:
            return {
                "answer": int(userInput),
                "question": question,
                "solution": solution
            }
        except:
            print("Only numbers are allowed")


mathFunctions = [
    oddOrEven,
    muliply
]


def mathQuestion():
    return mathFunctions[randint(0, len(mathFunctions)-1)]()
```

[Github repo](https://github.com/HenrikDK2/PythonMathQuestion/tree/master)

Comment: Check my edit ;)

Comment: Yes, but i can print result["question"] and it returns a string with the question, so i don't see the problem.

Comment: The logic in `gameLoop()` looks flawed (and likely to break). I certainly don't see the need for the use of `global`.

Comment: That is not the current problem, can you please explain why instead of just pointing something out so i can learn from my mistake?